# ImageResizer crashing on large images

Tags: imageresizer

Im using the awesome ImageResizing component and am experiencing an "Out of memory" error when trying to upload and read images that are about 100MB in size. It may seem large, but we're a printers so many people do need to provide images of that size.

The line of code that fails is:

ImageResizer.ImageBuilder.Current.Build(Server.MapPath(strImagePath), Server.MapPath(strThumbPath), new ResizeSettings("maxheight=" + "150"+ "&maxwidth=" + "238"));

This is probably the GDI itself failing, but is there any workaround other than detecting the error occured and letting the user know?

Thanks in advance
Al

Comment: File size of the image (jpg/png/etc..) doesn't matter so much as what its resolution and color depth is. a 1000x1000 image at 32bit will require ~4 megs of ram just for the raw uncompressed pixel data. You say you're printers, so you're most likely dealing with even larger images.

Comment: Thanks for your response. How can you work out what ram it would need based on the dimensions? Approximately of course. The images I've been testing is 19000 X 13000 so pretty damn big!

Comment: 19000 * 13000 * (bit_depth/8) = 942 megabytes for a 32bit image.

Answer (score 4):

A 100MB jpeg generally decompresses to around 8 gigabytes in bitmap form. Your only chance of getting that to work is getting 16 GB of RAM and running the process in 64-bit mode.

Alternatively, you could try [libvips](http://www.vips.ecs.soton.ac.uk/index.php?title=Libvips) - it's designed for gigantic image files. There's no .NET wrapper yet, but I really want to make one and get some ImageResizer integration going! Of course, without anyone interested in funding that, it probably won't happen for a while....

Comment: Hey Computer Linguist - thanks for your response. Interestingly though, the code I posted does sometimes work, on a machine that only has 4GB of RAM - so that's weird right?

Comment: Not really. If the image was using near-maximum quality, it's possible that it's only around 3GB in bitmap form, and thus the success is dependent upon how fragmented your memory space is, and how much of it is free. This kind of work needs huge, unfragmented blocks of ram.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Lilith River](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12375533/10952119), libvips is capable of resizing large images with low memory needs. Fortunately, there is now a full [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) binding for .NET available: https://github.com/kleisauke/net-vips/.

It should be able to process 100MB jpeg files without any problems.